# Датчики iPhone, вывести информацию о них

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, embedded

Нужно отобразить информацию о всех имеющихся датчиках на iPhone, есть ли функция сбора информации по датчикам? Перерыл интернет, не нашел, либо как это сделать вручную?

Comment: Тут нужно по каждому датчику отдельно инфу брать, скажем, Core Motion для наклонов, для датчиков освещения другой фреймворк, для микрофона Core Audio скорее всего и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [библиотеку](https://github.com/andrealufino/ALSystemUtilities), надеюсь, поможет.